# Cannot redirect to the url when using Ajax $.post()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the JavaScript. I want to send the data through `$.post()`, however it did not redirect to the page `accounting.php`, only `alert(data);` output something.

```
    $('#next').unbind('click').click(function() {

        $('#order01').ajaxSubmit(); 
        $('#order02').ajaxSubmit(); 
        $('#order03').ajaxSubmit(); 
        $('#order04').ajaxSubmit(); 
        var order01 = $('#order01').formSerialize();
        var order02 = $('#order02').formSerialize();
        var order03 = $('#order03').formSerialize();
        var order04 = $('#order04').formSerialize();
        var order = order01 + "&" + order02 + "&" + order03 + "&" + order04;


        $.post("/accounting.php", order, function(data) {
            alert(data);
            window.location.href = "/accounting.php?" + data;
        });


    });
```

Comment: what is in `data` ? is it object .???

Comment: Do you see the `data` correctly in the alert box?

Comment: You probably want to store `data` in the `localStorage` and read it after the redirect. That way you won't have issues with the URL escaping.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `data` to query parameters

Use [$.param()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/)

```
 $.param(data);
```

Like

```
window.location.href = "/accounting.php?" + $.param(data);
```

Comment: its related to redirect not related to data

Comment: Thanks for you comment. Maybe the question is not clear enough. I now change alert(data) to alert(order), and change another line to  window.location.href = "/accounting.php?" + order. It could redirect to accounting.php but still could not pass the value of "order" to that page. When I tried $.param(order) it just broke the message in "order" into single character like "0=d&1=i&2=s&3=h..." (The original data in "order" is supposed to be "dish01=xxx&dish02=xxx&dish03=xxx&dish04=xxx")

Comment: @JackLin Don't use param() with a string. Use ` "/accounting.php?" + order;`  What do you see `print_r($_POST);` in accounting.php